# If $\beta=0.{a_1}^{k}{a_2}^{k}{a_3}^{k}\cdots\in\mathbb Q$, then $\alpha=0.a_1a_2a_3\cdots\in\mathbb Q$?

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

> **Question** : For every **even** $k\ge 4$, is the following $(\star)$ true?
>
> $$\begin{align}\text{If $\beta=0.{a_1}^{k}{a_2}^{k}{a_3}^{k}\cdots\in\mathbb Q$, then $\alpha=0.a_1a_2a_3\cdots\in\mathbb Q$.}\qquad(\star)\end{align}$$
>
> Here, $a_i$ is the $i$-th decimal place of $\alpha$.

**Example** : For $k=2,\alpha=0.12345,$ we have $\beta=0.1491625.$

**Motivation** : I've been able to prove that the answer is **NO** for $k=2$, and that the answer is **YES** for every **odd** $k\ge 3$. The answer seems YES for **any** $k\ge 3$, but I'm facing difficulty for treating every even $k$ in general. Can anyone help?

*Update* : I crossposted to [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/151131/if-beta-0-a-1ka-2ka-3k-cdots-in-mathbb-q-then-alpha-0-a-1a).

**P.S.** The followings are the counterexamples for $k=2$.
$$\alpha=0.2372377237772377772377777\cdots\Rightarrow \beta=0.\overline{49}.$$
$$\alpha=0.1842184242184242421842424242\cdots\Rightarrow \beta=0.\overline{164}.$$
$$\alpha=0.183423471831834234718318318342347\cdots\Rightarrow \beta=0.\overline{1649}.$$

Comment: Have you got a counter-example for $k=2$? Actually, since $a_i$ are digits, thus $0 \le a_i \le 9$, I would expect that the condition on $\beta$ (that it, there is a repeating pattern in $\beta$ digits), implies also a repeating pattern in $\alpha$ digits, thus $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @arbautjc: Yes. For example, $\alpha=0.237237723777237777\cdots.$

Comment: Oh, yes $7^2=49=2^2 || 3^2$, thus you can play with patterns as you wish. Nice! This works because $\alpha$ may be not unique, and if you can cut a concatenated square (or k-th power in general) in different ways to get smaller squares (k-th powers), you can build an irrational number. +1, very interesting question ;-)

Comment: Related: http://cbarker.net/blog/projects/science/power-concatenation

Comment: @mathlove: I am confused. Does a rational number $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}$ not have a non-periodic part followed by a periodic path, written as $\alpha = 0.a_1 \cdots a_p \overline{ a_{p+1} \cdots a_{p+q}}$?

Is the number $0.2372377237772377772377777\cdots$ not irrational?

Comment: @johannesvalks: The number I wrote can be written as the following. It is an irrational number. $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\{\left\{0.23+\sum_{k=1}^{i}\big(7\times 10^{-2-i}\big)\right\}\times 10^{-(i+4)(i-1)/2}\right\}$$

Comment: The Answer is YES for $k = 4, 6, 8$. Proving the general case seems beyond me. But the reasoning is that if the statement is FALSE then you have found different sequences that square to the same thing. By eye, you can verify that for $k = 4$ this cannot happen. For example $3^4 = 81$ and this is the only way to get an $8$ in the decimal expansion for $\beta$ so a $3$ in $\alpha$ doesn't help its irrationality. Likewise $\{6,7,8,9\}$ also don't help. They only collision you get is with something like: $0.1\bar{5}$ and $0.2\bar{4}$ but they are rational.

Comment: Anyway, I can easily see that there is a unique 'inverse' for $k = 6,8$ too. Hence if $\beta$ is rational then $\alpha$ is too. To prove the general case it would suffice to show that the set of numbers $\{2^k,3^k,4^k,5^k,6^k,7^k,8^k,9^k\}$ have unique substrings in them for some sufficiently big $k$. But that is outside my skill.

Answer (score 3):

The general problem is this: 
We are given a (finite) alphabet $\Sigma$ and a map $f\colon \Sigma\to\Sigma ^*$.
Via $a_1a_2\cdots \mapsto f(a_1)f(a_2)\cdots $ we can extend $f$ to the set $\Sigma^*$ of words, but even to the set $\Sigma^\omega$ of infinite strings over the alphabet $\Sigma$.

For $v,w\in\Sigma^*$ we introduce the relation is-suffix-of:
$$ v\preceq w\iff \exists u\in \Sigma^*\colon uv=w$$

The question is:

> **Q:** Is it possible for $\alpha\in\Sigma^\omega$ that $f(\alpha)$ is eventually periodic, but $\alpha$ is not?

The answer depends on $f$, of course. Let us assume that $f$ has the following property:

**Property X.** If $a,b\in\Sigma$, $w\in\Sigma^*$, $f(a)\preceq f(b)\preceq f(wa)$, then $a=b$.

Now assume $\alpha\in\Sigma^\omega$ is not eventually periodic and $f(\alpha)$ is eventually periodic. Say, for $p>0$ we have that $f(\alpha)_n=f(\alpha)_{n+p}$ for all $n>N$.
For each $n\in\Bbb N$ with $|f(\alpha_1\cdots\alpha_{n-1})|>N$, define $\phi(n)=\langle \alpha_n,|f(\alpha_1\cdots\alpha_{n})|\bmod p\rangle$.
Since $\phi$ takes only finitely many values, some value $\langle a_0,r_0\rangle$ occurs infinitely often.
Then by property X, for all $n$ with $\phi(n)=\langle a_0,r_0\rangle$, $\phi(n-1)$ is either undefined or always takes the same value $\langle a_1,r_1\rangle$.
By repeating the argument, for all such $n$, $\phi(n-2)$ is undefined or takes the same value $\langle a_2,r_2\rangle$, and so on. Again by finiteness, we will at some point find $\langle a_i,r_i\rangle=\langle a_j,r_j\rangle$ with $i< j$. From then on, we will have $\langle a_{i+k},r_{i+k}\rangle=\langle a_{j+k},r_{j+k}\rangle$ for all $k\ge 0$ and hence $\alpha$ is eventually periodic.

Thus we have shown:

> If $f$ has property X, then the answer to question Q is "no".

Now we need to check if property X holds in the specific case where $\Sigma=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ and $f(a)$ is the decimal representation of the number $a^k$.
For odd $k$ this is clear because $\phi(10)=4$ and hence $a^k\equiv b^k\pmod{10}$ implies $a\equiv b\pmod{10}$, i.e., already $f(a)\preceq f(b)$ implies $a=b$.

For $k=2$, the $f(a)$ are
$$0,1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81 $$
and we see that $f(3)$ is a suffix of $f(7)$ and also $f(7)$ is a suffix of $f(23)$. Therefore property X does *not* hold here (and indeed the answer to question Q is "yes", as is shown by letting $\alpha$ be a concatenation of $23$ and $7$ in a non-repetitive pattern.

For $k=4$, the $f(a)$ are
$$0,1,16,81,256,625,1296,2401,4096,6561$$
Only $f(1)$ is suffix of other $f(a)$, namely of $f(3)$, $f(7)$, $f(9)$.
But (by inspection) neither $8$ nor $240$ nor $656$ is obtainable as a suffix of some $f(w)$.
Hence property X holds.

For $k=6$, the $f(a)$ are
$$ 0, 1, 64, 729, 4096, 15625, 46656, 117649, 262144, 531441.$$
Again, only $f(1)$ is a suffix (and this will be the cse for all even exponents), but only of $f(9)$ and $53144$ is no obtainable as suffix of some $f(w)$.
Hence property X holds.

For $k=8$, we have
$$0,1, 256, 6561, 65536, 390625, 1679616, 5764801, 16777216, 43046721$$
and need only verify that $656$, $576480$, $4304672$ are not obtainable as suffix. Check.

The main conjecture is

**Conjecture 1.** Property X holds for all $k\ge 3$.

Also, we have a subordinate conjecture

**Conjecture 2.** If $k\ge 3$ and $f(a)$ is a suffix of $f(b)$ for two digits $a,b$, then $a=b$ or $a=1$.

Some work on this:
Let $0\le a<b\le 9$. Then $d_n:=b^n-a^n$ follows the recursion $d_0=0$, $d_1=b-a$, $d_{n+1}=(a+b)d_n-abd_{n-1}$. We consider only the last $m$ digits of this sequence, i.e., work modulo $10^m$ for various $m$. As there are only finitely many values, the sequence is eventually periodic.
We can simplify mattes by working modulo $5^m$:
We are only interested in cases where $a,b\notin\{0,5\}$. Hence $ab$ is invertible $\pmod {5^m}$ and the sequence is immediately periodic and more
specifically $d_n\equiv 0$ implies $d_{rn}\equiv 0$ for all $r\in\Bbb N_0$.
In other words, there exists $p\in \Bbb N_0$ such that $d_n\equiv 0\pmod{5^m}$ iff $p\mid n$. Write $p(a,b,m)$ for this $p$.

For given $2\le a<b\le 9$, start with $m_0=2$ and recursively let $$m_{n+1}=\lfloor \log_{10}a^{p(a,b,m_n)}\rfloor+1=\lfloor p(a,b,m_n)\log_{10}a\rfloor +1$$ be then number of digits
of the smallest power of $a$ that agrees with the same power of $b$ in the last $m_n$ digits.
Then conjecture 2 holds at least for digits $a,b$ for all $k$ with $4\le k<p(a,b,m_n)$.
For all interesting pairs $(a,b)$, i.e., both of same parity and $5\notin\{a,b\}$, one verifies numerically that $m_1\ge 4$, $m_2>75$. (For a specific example: with $a=2, b=8$, we have $m_0=2$, $m_1=4$, $m_2=76$, $m_3=15936395277450702718847601312677127001857150683576647$).
Also, one verifies  $p(a,b,75)\ge4235164736271501695341612503398209810256958007812500$ for all these $(a,b)$.
This shows that conjecture 2 holds for $k\le 4235164736271501695341612503398209810256958007812500$.

In order to show conjecture 1 for the same range of $k$, it suffices to investigate if one can build $\frac{b^k-1}{10}$ for those $b>1$ with $b^k\equiv 1\pmod{10}$.